# A question about the double article in I Timothy 3:16

Tags: greek

> μεγα εστιν το της ευσεβειας μυστηριον [TR]
>
> ... great is the mystery of godliness [KJV]
>
> ... great is the of piety mystery [EGNT]
>
> ... great is the secret of piety [YLT]

Since the first article is, I understand, the singular, neuter, accusative it attaches, I take it, to μυστηριον.

Since the second article is, I understand, the singular, feminine, genitive it attaches, I take it, to ευσεβειας.

Therefore, is it correct to say that the very literal translation could be correctly rendered as :

> ... the (that of piety) mystery ... ?

Comment: I would agree with your analysis

Comment: There's nothing out of the ordinary here. That's simply the way Greek writers often wrote possessives: one noun enclosed by the second article and noun pair of words. Remember that in Greek word order is more flexible because word endings determined the meaning, not word order. So it would mean "the mystery of godliness" whatever the word order.

Comment: the interlinear like translation you are looking for should be "godliness's or piety's mystery".

Answer (score 0):

It's a perfectly ordinary structure, though less so than in older Greek.  It serves to sandwich one idea within another, here a genitive inside a neuter construction.  They can be more complex as well, with entire phrases on the inside; using lower case for the article and uppercase for the word it goes with, this is: a b BA, but I've seen a b c C B A as well.

It's not just a matter of word order, packaging one phrase inside another can serve as emphasis, sometimes to make clear a logical structure.

Comment: So, your translation would be . . . . .  ?